# Web Deploy parameterization issue

Tags: xpath, sitecore, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy, parameterization

I'm running into an issue with one of our Sitecore projects. The problem is that certain parameters won't get replaced... I've reproduced the issue in the GitHub repository shown below.

https://github.com/jopmiddelkamp/Web-Deploy-Parameters-issue

With the `parameters.xml` file below I'm trying to replace mail server values for the Sitecore EXM MAT.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
  <parameter name="Mail Server" description="Mail server to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServer__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServer']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/exm/eds/smtpSettings/server/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="Mail Server User Name" description="Mail Server User Name to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerUserName__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServerUserName']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/exm/eds/smtpSettings/userName/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="Mail Server Password" description="Mail Server Password to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerPassword__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServerPassword']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/exm/eds/smtpSettings/password/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="Mail Server Port" description="Mail Server Port to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerPort__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServerPort']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/exm/eds/smtpSettings/port/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="EXM Mail Server SSL or TLS Enabled" description="EXM Mail Server SSL/TLS enabled to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerSslOrTlsEnabled__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/exm/eds/smtpSettings/startTls/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="EXM Mail Server Authentication Method" description="EXM Mail Server Authentication Method to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerAuthenticationMethod__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/exm/eds/smtpSettings/authenticationMethod/text()" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

This generates the `SetParameters.xml` file as shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="ParametersTest" />
  <setParameter name="Mail Server" value="__MailServer__" />
  <setParameter name="Mail Server User Name" value="__MailServerUserName__" />
  <setParameter name="Mail Server Password" value="__MailServerPassword__" />
  <setParameter name="Mail Server Port" value="__MailServerPort__" />
  <setParameter name="EXM Mail Server SSL or TLS Enabled" value="__MailServerSslOrTlsEnabled__" />
  <setParameter name="EXM Mail Server Authentication Method" value="__MailServerAuthenticationMethod__" />
</parameters>
```

So far so good! I want the values to be replaced with the `__placeholder__` structure so our VSTS release proces can replace those values with the right environment variables.

Now the problem is that on deployment the `userName` and `password` nodes won't get replaced in the `\App_Config\Include\EmailExperience\Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.config` file. The result is shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <exm>
            <eds>
                ...
                <smtpSettings type="Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.SmtpSettings, Sitecore.EDS.Core" singleInstance="true">
                    <server>__MailServer__</server>
                    <port>__MailServerPort__</port>
                    <userName></userName>
                    <password></password>
                    <authenticationMethod>__MailServerAuthenticationMethod__</authenticationMethod>
                    <startTls>__MailServerSslOrTlsEnabled__</startTls>
                    <proxySettings ref="exm/eds/proxySettings" />
                </smtpSettings>
                ...
            </eds>
        </exm>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This is weird because the xpath in the match attribute is exactly the same as the `Mail Server Port` parameter for example... I've also tried to update the `parameters.xml` file as shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
  <parameter name="Mail Server" description="Mail server to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServer__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServer']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//*[local-name()='server']/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="Mail Server User Name" description="Mail Server User Name to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerUserName__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServerUserName']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//*[local-name()='userName']/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="Mail Server Password" description="Mail Server Password to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerPassword__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServerPassword']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//*[local-name()='password']/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="Mail Server Port" description="Mail Server Port to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerPort__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\Sitecore\.Smtp\.config$" match="//sitecore/settings/setting[@name='MailServerPort']/@value" />
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//*[local-name()='port']/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="EXM Mail Server SSL or TLS Enabled" description="EXM Mail Server SSL/TLS enabled to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerSslOrTlsEnabled__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//*[local-name()='startTls']/text()" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="EXM Mail Server Authentication Method" description="EXM Mail Server Authentication Method to enter into config" tags="Hidden,NoStore" defaultValue="__MailServerAuthenticationMethod__">
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="App_Config\\Include\\EmailExperience\\Sitecore\.EDS\.Providers\.CustomSmtp\.config$" match="//*[local-name()='authenticationMethod']/text()" />
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

But this results in the same output... I can't find anything about any reserved names for the `userName` and `password` node names...

This is driving me crazy as I can't find a solution. Now I hope anyone here has experinced this issue before and knows how to solve it.

Kind regards,
Jop Middelkamp